# Android Studio или Xamarin?

Tags: java, c#, android-studio, xamarin

Около года работаю в Android Studio, а совсем недавно узнал что есть такая программа - Xamarin. В данной программе можно писать одновременно для Android, iOS и WP.

Насколько получается оптимизировано приложение после компиляции в этой программе? Например, я написал программку в AS и точно такую же в Xamarin. Будет ли у программ большая разница в занимаемом месте, потреблении оперативной памяти? Все таки AS изначально сделана для написания приложений на Android, а Xamarin как-то сам преобразует код.

На каком языке все же лучше писать - Java или C#?

Comment: будет не оптимизирована ни под одну из поддерживаемых платформ, медленее, существенно больше по размеру приложения и потреблению ресурсов, с плохой кастомизируемостью и вообще одни недостатки. Единственный сомнительный плюс - за раз сразу под три платформы с недоприложениями.

Comment: Android Studio - IDE, среда разработки под android, а не платформа. Для нативного Android на шарпе не пишут - Java, С, С++, Go, Kotlin ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Однозначно ответить на этот вопрос нельзя. Всё зависит от того, какие технологии вам нужны. Если вам не нужен .NET, то, возможно, и смысла в использовании Xamarin нет.

Xamarin приложения в памяти телефона размещают еще и Mono Runtime - необходимые компоненты, для работы Xamarin приложений. Xamarin, несмотря на хорошую рекламу и распространённость, немного "сыровата". Это особенно заметно при проектировании UI и работе с WCF.

Конечно же советую попробовать самому и сделать выводы на основе собственных ощущений:) (Xamarin встроен в VS2015 VS2017)

Answer (score 3):

Чтоб писать на андроде на (нужно знать):

- На Java:  java + api android
- На C#: C# + Java + api android
- На < x language>#: < x language> + Java + api android

Чтоб писать кроссплатформенные приложения на Xamarin(Android/IOS):

- C# + JAVA + ObjectiveC + api xamarin + api android + api IOS

**Выводы делайте сами))**